# nested select statement subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having two tables students and other is marks
students contain all students info like first name, last name and unique idnumber
and marks contain marks obtain by students
for each student marks are stored for each year i.e student from third year will have 3 entries in marks table

now i want to design a query which contain students info and all three years marks in single record

output should be like this :

`First Name | Last Name | 1st Year Marks | 2nd Year Marks | 3rd Year Marks`

Comment: It'll be easier to help if you post your SQL statement, too.

Comment: Or at the very least the tables full definition

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your nested statement looks like, but you want something along the lines of this:

```
select
    s.firstname,
    s.lastname,
    sum(case when m.year = m2.minyear then m.mark else 0 end) as `1st Year Marks`,
    sum(case when m.year = m2.minyear+1 then m.mark else 0 end) as `2nd Year Marks`,
    sum(case when m.year = m2.minyear+2 then m.mark else 0 end) as `3rd Year Marks`
from
    students s
    inner join marks m on
        s.student_id = m.student_id
    inner join (select student_id, min(year) as minyear from marks group by student_id) m2 on
        s.student_id = m2.student_id
group by
    s.firstname,
    s.lastname
```

I did conditional sums here, as well as dynamic years, since students could arrive at different times. This would be easier if you had a Year table with like "Freshman", "Sophomore", etc in it, and then kept track of when the Student completed that Year, but this will work, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

try below query.. i am considering students and marks have sstudent id in column

select stu.firstname + '|' +stu.lastname+ '|' +marks.1styr+ '|' +marks.2nd yr+ '|'+marks.3rdyr from students as stu,marks where stu.uniqueid=marks.uniqueid